# Group Transactions - Spring Data JPA- Boot1.4.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to have the group of transactions to be executed for a user action from the UI. If any one of below 3 failed, need to role back entire 3 transactions.
1) insert the data in one table 
2) update the data in another table 
3) send email to the user

I'm trying to use spring data jpa,Can i achieve my requirement? If not, please guide how to achieve.
If i use below code,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assets/addEmployeeAsset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addEmployeeAsset(@RequestBody EmployeeAsset employeeAsset) {
        System.out.println("inside addEmployeeAsset restcontroller--");
        employeeAssetDao.save(employeeAsset);
        assetDao.updateAssetAfterAllocation(employeeAsset.getAssetid());
        assetService.sendEmail();
    } 

public interface EmployeeAssetDao extends CrudRepository<EmployeeAsset, Long> {
}

public interface AssetDao extends CrudRepository<Asset,Long>{
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
     @Query(value = "update Asset a SET a.active = ?1 where a.assetid=?2")
     List<Asset> updateAssetAfterAllocation(String active,String assetid);
}

@RestController
public class AssetService {
    public void sendEmail();
}
```

Comment: imho your design is wrong already... Your controller should only be a translation layer/integration layer which should call the service layer which executes the actions. The lines you have in your controller should be in a service which itself should be marked `@Transactional`. Call the service from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `@Transactional` annotation above addEmployeeAsset method

Comment: Which is very bad advice... You shouldn't make your web layer transactional.

Comment: You mean we should move 3 transactions to one method in service class and put the annotation there?

Comment: Correct. That way you can also test (and reuse) your business logic. You only  need an adapter/integration for a different entry point (like a soap web service or messaging gateway).

Comment: I just answer what OP need. I will notice to give advice in the next answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: As of now thanks to Anh & Deinum. I'm writing the business logic now. let me move all these method together under one method in service layer and make it transactional and will test it. I will come back and post my answer soon.